# Website to keep track of which beers I try and how I rate them

Tags: webapp-rec

I enjoy trying different brews and keeping track of how they tasted. Are there any websites out there that can do this? I've tried Hop Chart but it is unbearable to use.

If the site has a nice mobile application or website that would be a bonus.

Comment: there's always blogger :)

Comment: +1... beer is important and you certainly want to avoid having a bad one twice.

Comment: I've actually just been using a Google Spreadsheet to keep track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RateBeer](http://ratebeer.com) immediately comes to mind.

You might also try [Coastr](http://www.coastr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beer Advocate](http://beeradvocate.com/).

They have a large and active community.  It's been a go-to place for me after trying something and seeing what others have said about it/compared it to.

Comment: While I find Beer Advocate to be a very useful resource, it isn't a good tool for keeping track of any and all beers you've tried. The reason is that they expect you to type up a complete review. I may want to note that I tried a lambic and hated it (just for my future self) but I'm not about to write a review on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Untappd](http://untappd.com) is another option. It's a social check in service (like Foursquare) but instead of checking in to places you "check in" to beers.

You can also rate them and leave a note.

Comment: My biggest issue with Untappd is that you can't log your beers from within your computer's browser. It has to be on a mobile device (yuck)

Comment: @JoePhillips: That was my biggest complaint too, but they changed that a couple months ago. You can check in from any beer's page now.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using [Beer RAM](http://www.beerram.com) to keep track of this. It lets you give beers a star rating and add tasting notes. Later, you can just search for the beer and then you'll know if you've tried it and exactly what you thought.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BeerRiot](http://beerriot.com/).

Not that it matters, but it is written in [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) programming language.